# Which local ringed spaces are schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-theory

[This paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-142-00/S0002-9947-1969-0251026-X/S0002-9947-1969-0251026-X.pdf) gives a proof that the underlying topological spaces of affine schemes are precisely the [spectral spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_space) (compact, T0, sober, and the compact open subsets are closed under finite intersection and generate the topology; equivalently, they are the inverse limits of families of finite T0 spaces).

Instead of starting with a bare topological space, suppose we have a locally ringed space. If it is an affine scheme, then the underlying space is spectral, the supports of sections generate the topology, every restriction map of the sheaf is a localization of rings, etc.

Does anyone know whether we can impose restrictions (such as the ones I have just listed, and probably together with others) to guarantee that a given locally ringed space is actually an affine scheme?

[This poster](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13616/a-book-on-locally-ringed-spaces) asked something similar - whether locally ringed spaces had been classified in some way. This is not exactly what I'm looking for, but it would be interesting to know in any case.

Comment: Would this be better attempted at MathOverflow?

Comment: Yes, I think that MathOverflow is more appropriate for this question. But check out [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252009/properties-of-the-petit-zariski-topos/) (which didn't receive a conclusive answer).